# Ethereum Wallet: error of no key for given address or file

Tags: contract-development, dapps, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp

In etherum wallet I am getting an error of no key for given address or file during deployment of the contract. What will be the reason for the same?

[image: Screenshot]

```
contract User{

    string public userName;

    function User(string _name){

     userName = _name;

    }

}
```

Comment: It was fixed when you restarted it, right?

Comment: Yaa it got fixed when I restarted it.Also came to know that it happened because of key not matching.But now sure why when I restarted, it got resolved.

Comment: It's totally okay to [answer your own question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). This will help users in the future who may face the same problems. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "restarting"? Can someone provide a more robust answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by restating the wallet.Just close the wallet one time and open it again.