# Error "no key for given address or file" when unlocking coinbase account

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, accounts, json-rpc, coinbase

Using json-rpc `eth_unlockAccount()` method I can unlock everyone of my node accounts except **coinbase**. When trying to unlock coinbase account, geth responds with the message:

> no key for given address or file.

I've bee reading [Ethereum Wallet: error of no key for given address or file](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/ethereum-wallet-error-of-no-key-for-given-address-or-file) but I am not using Ethereum Wallet, but just json-rpc calls to geth node. Nevertheless I have restarted geth node, as recommended in the answer, but still the same error.

How can I unlock coinbase account? Why the error:

> no key for given address or file.

P.S.: Trying to unlock the coinbase account directly with command line, same result:

```
$ geth --testnet --unlock 0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937
```

> Fatal: Failed to unlock account 0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937 (no key for given address or file)

Comment: Are you sure you actually own the key to your `coinbase` account? The coinbase defaults to your first address, but it can also be set manually to whatever you want.

Comment: Yes. I have reset the password using command geth account update , but still same error.

Comment: My coinbase account is 47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937 and there exist a file .ethereum/keystore/UTC--2016-08-12T16-23-07.956658700Z--47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937 . The thing is there are 6 more accounts defined on geth, but they have not any associated file at folder .ethereum/keystore/ . Quite strange! Has it something to do with the problem I am reporting? The only account I cannot unlock has an associate file on .ethereum/keystore/ ...

Comment: Before you try to unlock via json-rpc, how about you unlock directly from the geth console? Does this work?

Comment: Same result: $ geth --testnet --unlock 0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937

Fatal: Failed to unlock account 0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937 (no key for given address or file)

Comment: I think problem could be related to messing up mainnet with testnet accounts... I defined coinbase account on mainnet, but I am trying to unlock it on testnet. That could be the origin of the problem...

Comment: Yes, it keeps a separate keystore for the testnet accounts. You can copy the keys in `.ethereum/keystore` to `ethereum/testnet/keystore` and you should be all set.

Comment: @TjadenHess has the real answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We were getting the same error and it turned out that there were two conflicting keyfiles.  One in the default (~/.ethereum) and one in a custom location that we had specified using --datadir.

In the end it was just a case of cleaning up the scripts we were using to deploy the geth node to make sure that we consistently only used one or the other keystore (we went with the default in our case)

Once we had done that, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could just specify location of --keystore ( https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options ).

Answer (score 2):

in geth console issue

```
web3.personal.importRawKey("private key", "password")
```

After that I was able to unlock

Answer (score 0):

Check if Key is present in ".ethereum/testnet/keystore" for testnet and ".ethereum/keystore" for mainnet.

Key file name will have the public key included in it