# Specify which keyfile to use

Tags: go-ethereum

I have been getting the error:

> Failed to unlock account "" (no key for given address or file)

I did some reading and found that the problem could be caused by conflicting keyfiles. The solution was to specify the keyfile to use. How would I do that? I found the solution here:

> [Error "no key for given address or file" when unlocking coinbase account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/error-no-key-for-given-address-or-file-when-unlocking-coinbase-account)

The command I am using is:

```
geth --datadir node1/ --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "personal,db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1 --unlock '0x""' --password passwords.txt --mine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in your command i guess.

```
The command I am using is:

geth --datadir node1/ --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "personal,db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1 --unlock '0x""' --password passwords.txt --mine
```

Try to use --unlock 0